# Replace single words/lines with text from multiple inputs

Tags: html, replace, find, line

What would be the best method for replacing variables/words/lines of text in a larger "paragraph" of code?

Example:

Lorem ipsum dolor $SIT amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam condimentum dolor ut est faucibus dapibus. Donec molestie dictum nisi, eu euismod $SAPIEN gravida in. Aliquam dictum, tellus eu facilisis laoreet, sapien nunc placerat turpis, eu pretium augue eros vel lectus. Quisque condimentum lorem $EROS, vel pharetra tortor.

I want to be able to enter text in a textbox/prompt to replace the "Variables" $SIT, $SAPIEN, $EROS with actual values automatically.
I trust I've made myself obscure? :P

I'm n00b at any sort of coding.  I only know some basic HTML, PHP, and Java.  But please give me a clear solution with an example or link or more help.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You must utilize JavaScript if you want to do it client-side, and any of the server-side ones [PHP, Python, Ruby] if you want to do it that way. In all of these languages there are equivalents of "string replace" functions, that'll take list of strings to search, list of strings to replace and subject that they will be working on. Solution for JS and PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

The way that you'll do it is up to you.

Comment: I would like to use JavaScript, but I don't think it can do exactly what I wanted; My actual use would be to substitute template filenames with real ones in some lines for HTML. And from what I've tried, you can't use HTML characters within the JavaScript string.